# Error when trying to execute "firebase deploy" in React App

Tags: node.js, firebase, deployment

When trying to deploy my React application, after having done "npm run build" and after configure the hosting in "firebase.json" file, the whole firebase process runs correctly until I get the message "Error: An unexpected error has occurred." checking the file "firebase-debug.log" I find this problem:

```
TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at release (C:\Users\Jhonny\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.0.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release.js:47:10)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

This problem is solved by directly modifying the Node file but then another similar message appears, and so on, also I don't think it is the correct solution.

Node version: 14.17 LTS

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you forget to export the function like:

```
export const func = functions. // ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, in the "functions/index.js" file, I commented all the example lines, as I did not need them yet, and when I uncommented them, all including the example, the deployment was executed in its entirety and my React application is now online.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, upgrade node by running the following command in your terminal:

```
npm install node
```